# which devices support the DJI mobile SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/product_introduction.html#Supported-Products

what does the "-" mean?

Does it mean that spark, mavic can not be accessed and controlled by mobile SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The "-" is for the accessories list (not applicable on the specified products).

Spark and Mavic are definitely supported by the mobile SDK.

Comment: ok~ and i have seen some turtorials for iOS, we can use SDK for captureing the scene ,managing the media etc. But  i was wondering that if i can control the drone directly by programming using SDK.

Comment: and if i can control the movement of the drone, does the obstacle avoid work at the same time?

Comment: As long as you are not in sport mode which disables the collision avoidance, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can control drone directly with mobile SDK.

You can use virtual stick input for this. It allows to send 4 axis valus to copter: pitch, roll, yaw, throttle.

You can find some information about this in [Simulator tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/SimulatorDemo.html).

[Virtual sticks documentation](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/component-guide-flightController.html#virtual-sticks)

obstacle avoidance can be turned on and off throug SDK calls. (look at Flight Assistant)